# point on this line doesn't make sense

Tags: interpolation

This is trivial by I'm stumped. I am trying to find the $x$-coordinate of a point on a line so that I can generate parallel diagonal lines on a graph- see image.

My slope is $m=-1$ and one point $(x_1,y_1)$ is $(1000,0)$. I would like to find the $x$-coordinate of my line at $y=100$.

I'm using the equation $y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$ but the answer $x=900$ does not make sense to me. Where am I going off?

$100-0 = -1(x-1000)$

$100 = -x + 1000$

$x = 900$

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be looking at equations of the type $y=kx+n$ because the graph is a logarithmic plot!

Comment: It does not make sense to have x or y coordinate as 0 on this log-log plot. Are you sure it's not $10^0$?

Comment: @Rohan It most certainly is not!

Comment: @5xum: are there log equations for solving this problem easily? I found this log(y) = m log(x) + b from here http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/69930.html which may work for me....